# Redirect without invoke onPageStarted

Tags: android, browser, webview, android-webview

It a sample question, can i redirect to another URL without make onPageStarted invoked?, without edit my java code

it will help me to test my app's security, i hope any one have idea if it possible :).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `<iframe>` because `onPageStarted` will not be called when the contents of an embedded frame changes. If this is not a choice for you, I'm afraid there is no way to stop calling `onPageStarted`.

Another possible way (maybe this is my imagination) is to modify Android source code. To achieve this, you can follow the steps mentioned [there](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading). Basically, you need to download Android source, build it, and modify some code (maybe delete `onPageStarted`). This can be complicated and I'm not sure whether this can work.